# sql code to convert varchar colum to int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck on converting a varchar column **schedule** containing the following data  0, 1, 2, 3,4,8,9,10,11,12,15,16,17,18,19  to  INT. I know, please don't ask why this schedule column was not created as INT initially, long story.

So I tried this, but it doesn't work. and give me an error:

```
select CAST(schedule AS int) from shift_test:
```

the query should check if the numbers representing days are found in the schedule filed using the sql code below

```
select empid, case when ((DateDiff(hour,'01-01-2014 07:00' , '01-01-2014 00:00')/ 24 )% 15) in ( CAST(schedule AS int))
then 'A' else '*' end as shift_A from Shift_test
```

After executing i get this error.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int.

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Are you sure that there are no records with an empty string or null value?  Your syntax is correct

Comment: are you saying the column contains a string like '0, 1, 2, 3,4,8,9,10,11,12,15,16,17,18,19' or multiple records with indivudal integer values such as '1'

Answer (score 0):

Use `ISNUMERIC()` test if you are using version 2008 or 2008R2. In SQL SERVER 2012 you can use `TRY_CAST()` function, which checks if the data conversion is allowed for given literal.

Mock up code for SQL Server 2008/R2:

```
Select col1, col2,
case
   when <condition> and isnumeric(col2) then cast(col2 as int)
   else <do whatever...>
end
as converted_col2
from <yourtable>;
```

For SQL Server 2012:

```
Select col1, col2,
case
   when <condition> then try_cast(col2 as int)
   else <do whatever...>
end
as converted_col2
from <yourtable>;
```

*Example with SQl Server 2008*

```
declare @T table (empid int, schedule varchar(2)) ;

insert into @T(empid, schedule) values (1, '1');
insert into @T(empid, schedule) values (2, '2');
insert into @T(empid, schedule) values (3, '03');
insert into @T(empid, schedule) values (4, '4');
insert into @T(empid, schedule) values (5, '05');
insert into @T(empid, schedule) values (6, 'A');

select empid, 
   case
    when ISNUMERIC(schedule) = 1 
       and ((DateDiff(hour,'01-01-2014 07:00' , '10-01-2014 00:00')/ 24 )% 15)  
       in ( CAST(schedule AS int)) then 'A'
    else '*' 
   end 
   as shift_A 
from @T;
```

Comment: isnumeric works by converting the varchar colum to int as expected but is not efficeint. it scape these values. 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19

Comment: any additional help will be much appriciated.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC()` tests whether the literal you supplied is a numeric literal or not, if yes you can cast it to any number type. Post the schema with some rows and the output you want to get for additional help.

Comment: its really hard pasting the output. but what i want is sql to check if these values (0, 1, 2, 3,4,8,9,10,11,12,15,16,17,18,19) exist in the schedule varchar colum to output A else output * if it dose not exist

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question well. Please see my updates with some made up table stuffs. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

@ Binaya Ive added my code for more help.

The schedule column contain (0, 1, 2, 3,4,8,9,10,11,12,15,16,17,18,19) which is varchar.
i want to output **A** if  after this calculation `((DateDiff(hour,'01-01-2014 07:00',startdate)/ 24   )% 15)` the result is found in the schedule column else if after the calculation and the result is not found output *****

```
;with Shift_runover  (shift_code,schedule,endd,startdate)
    -- Start at the beginning of shift.
    as 
    (select shift_code,schedule,Cast(end_date as DateTime) as endd,Cast(start_date as DateTime)as startdate from dbo.Shift_test
    union   all 

    -- Add hours up to the desired end date.
    select shift_code,schedule,endd,DateAdd(hour, 1,startdate)from Shift_runover where startdate<=endd),

    Extendedsamples as 
    (
    -- Calculate the number of days since the beginning of the first shift on 1/1/2014.
    select shift_code,schedule,startdate,DateDiff(hour,'01-01-2014 07:00',startdate)/ 24 as Days from Shift_runover ),
    Shifts as
     (
     -- the schedule column contain (0, 1, 2, 3,4,8,9,10,11,12,15,16,17,18,19) which is varchar.
     -- i want to output A if ((DateDiff(hour,'01-01-2014 07:00',startdate)/ 24   )% 15) is found in the schedule colume 
    select *,
    case when (DateDiff(hour,'01-01-2014 07:00',startdate)/ 24   )% 15 in(schedule)
    then 'A' else '*' end as shift_A

    from ExtendedSamples 
    )
    select *
    from Shifts
    option ( maxrecursion 0 )
```